# How to return any object with sys.stdout

Tags: python, bash, list, pipe

I am working on a python bash script and I would like to output a list from the first file to the next as so:

### sender.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
l = [1,2,4,6,8,"maybe some text"]
sys.stdout.write(Qs)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

### receiver.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
print(sys.stdin.readline())
```

### then do in bash

```
./sender_py | ./receiver
```

I know the problem is that this method can only read in a string, but is there any other way to pass any object. In this case, I am passing a list, but later I would like to try other objects such as pandas dfs.

Comment: use standard Json as text format for comunication. to send: json.dumps(your_object)  to recieve: d = json.loads(input_string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data serialization with [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html) :

sender.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pickle
l = [1,2,4,6,8,"maybe some text"]
sys.stdout.buffer.write(pickle.dumps(l))
```

receiver.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pickle
print(pickle.loads(sys.stdin.buffer.read()))
```